# Overloading concept: which function will be called and why?

Tags: oop

```
Class Student { 

 public void setName(String name){
   //Some implementation
 }

 public void setName(Object name){
  // some implementation
 }
}
```

I have a class Student with overload methods, i just want to know, which method will be called and why?

```
Student s = new Student()
 s.setName("abc");
```

**EDIT**
Language: JAVA

Comment: Have you tried to write a program to experiment with different inputs?

Comment: Not sure of that, but result could be different depending on the language you implement it on.

Comment: pls be more precise. What programming language do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will call `setName(String name)`function as you are passing the `String` and not object of `String`.